# Find and replace value of a key/value pair in a file

Tags: vbscript

I want to search for a value in a text file and replace it, like so:

Search for `value=` finds:

```
value=1122
```

Replace the value (1122) with something else (3344), result:

```
value=3344
```

Also, replacing what's left of the entire line would work just fine, meaning whatever comes after `value=` is also replaced with 3344.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
'Remove ^ from quoting command line. Quote, ampersand and brackets
Pttn = Replace(Arg(2), "^(", "(")
Pttn = Replace(Pttn, "^)", ")")
Pttn = Replace(Pttn, "^&", "&")
Pttn = Replace(Pttn, "^""", """")
Set regEx1 = New RegExp
If Instr(LCase(Arg(1)), "i") > 0 then
    regEx1.IgnoreCase = True
Else
    regEx1.IgnoreCase = False
End If 
regEx1.Global = False
regEx1.Pattern = Pttn 
Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
    Line=Inp.readline
    Line = RegEx1.Replace(Line, Arg(3)) 
    outp.writeline Line
Loop
```

To use

```
cscript //nologo c:\folder\filter.vbs replace i "=" "No equal sign" < "%systemroot%\win.ini" > OutputFile.txt
```

Filter reads and writes standard in and standard out only. These are only available in a command prompt.

```
filter <inputfile >outputfile
filter <inputfile | other_command
other_command | filter >outputfile
other_command | filter | other_command
```

**Replace**

```
filter replace {i|n} expression replace
filter repl {i|n} expression replace
```

Finds and replaces text using regular expressions.

Also used to extract substrings from a file.

Ampersands and brackets in expression must be escaped with the caret. Do not escape carets. Use hexidecimal code \x22 for quotes.

**SearchOptions**

```
i - ignore case
n - none
```

**Expression**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/f97kw5ka(v%3Dvs.84).aspx

**Replace**

The text to replace. Use $1, $2, $..., $n to specify sub matches in the replace string

**Example**

```
filter replace i "=" "No equal sign" < "%systemroot%\win.ini"
```

This searches for text within square brackets and replaces the line with cat followed by the text within brackets

```
Filter replace i "^\[^(.*^)\]" "cat$1" < %windir%\win.ini
```

This searches for any text and prints from the 11th character to the end of the line.

```
Filter replace i "^.{10}^(.*^)$" "$1" < %windir%\win.ini
```

This searches a CSV file and prints the second and fourth field

```
Filter replace i "^.+,^(.+^),.+,^(.+^)$" "$1,$2" < csv.txt
```